# TeXstudio doesn't see .bib file

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio

There is `a.tex` file which includes `b.tex` which includes `c.tex` which defines configures biblatex with few `.bib` files. And the problem is that TeXstudio cannot auto-complete citations in `a.tex`. Is there any possibility to associate documents with `.bib` in TeXstudio? Thanks.

Comment: Are you literally `\include`ing? I'm asking because to my very limited knowledge, in latex `\include` can not be nested, let alone the autocomplete in the editor...

Comment: Actually it's more about `\input`ting.

Comment: Works here. Are you using the most recent version of TXS? Please provide a minimal example which shows your issue.